# Go through all possibilities of a boolean array with recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

If we have an array of 4 booleans, what is the best way to generate all the possible values?

I want to find a solution that generates all the possibilities starting from 0 "False" to 4 "False" in the right order (first all the possibilities with 0 "False", then all the possibilities with 1 "False", then all the possibilities with 2 "False", etc...) :

- T T T T
- F T T T
- T F T T
- T T F T
- T T T F
- F F T T
- F T F T
- ...
- F F F F

I am trying to do it with recursion but I am missing something.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: Think in terms of binary.

Comment: Do you require recursion? or do you mean you tried it and you can't make it work, but a for loop would do?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Generate all binary sequences recursion", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, imagine a method:

```
void addPossible(ArrayList<String> array, String prefix, int numberOfSlots, int numberFalse) {
}
```

Imagine this method being called as addPossible(array, "TTT", 1, 0). In this case, you know you can have 1 true and no false choices, so you would add to the array just one value, the prefix + "T", or in this case "TTTT" and return.

Now, call this method a bunch of times:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 4; ++index) {
    addPossible(array, "", 4, index);
}
```

In other words, we'll call it with 4 slots, once for 0 false, then 1 false, etc.

Inside the method, you would call the method again, twice. I'm not going to show you all the code, but the calls would be:

```
addPossible(array, prefix + "T", numberOfSlots-1, numberFalse);
addPossible(array, prefix + "F", numberOfSlots-1, numberFalse-1);
```

The first case, it's because we're adding a T, so we still need all the falses. The second case, it's because we're adding an F, so we need one less false. In either case, we have added to the string, so the number of slots remaining is smaller.

There's more code to write. You haven't actually pushed anything onto the vector, and you haven't done the logic.

But perhaps you see how this works out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the numbers upto 2<sup>4</sup>, and the bits of the corresponding counter.
The order is a bit tricky, in principle you can use a BitSet to hold the booleans:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1 << 4; ++i) {
    BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { (long)i);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        if (bits.get(j)) {
        }
    }
}
```

The order seems to be i from 15 downto 0, and j from 3 downto 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   final int n = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        while (binary.length() < n)
            binary= "0" + binary;
        System.out.println(binary);
    }
   }
```

The output will be like this

> 0000
>   0001
>   0010
>   0011
>   0100
>   0101
>   0110
>   0111
>   1000
>   1001
>   1010
>   1011
>   1100
>   1101
>   1110
>   1111

You can consider the '0' as 'F' and '1' as 'T'

Comment: I don't think this is the same order as the one in the question. He said it needs the order to be the same

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to simply convert the values to binary strings, pad on the left with missing '0' characters and then do a one for one replacement.

```java
      for (int v : n) {
         String s = "000" + Integer.toBinaryString(v);
         s = s.substring(s.length() - 4, s.length()).replace("1", "T ").replace(
               "0", "F ");
         System.out.println(s);
      }
```